# Variation of QED gauge missing step

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gauge-theory, variational-calculus

I have several questions about this problem. I have been given a non-linear gauge condition for a QED theory:

$$F = \partial_{\mu}A^{\mu} + \frac{\lambda}{2}A_{\mu}A^{\mu}.$$

I have found online that assuming $\delta A_\mu = \partial_\mu \alpha$ it follows that:
$$ \delta F = \left(\partial_{\mu} + \lambda A_{\mu} \right)\partial^\mu \alpha.$$
I cannot see how this is the case. Shouldn't there be an extra term? And where did that factor of 2 come from?

Comment: You have too many $\mu$ indices in that expression, and the number of uncontracted indices doesn't match between $\partial_\mu$ and $A_\mu \partial^\mu$.  I would suggest checking your work carefully.

Comment: @J.Murray sorry there was a typo

Comment: @Triatticus there was a typo

Comment: Yeah I saw J.Murry already addressed that, as for your question itself, you should show work on how you would determine $\delta F$ using the given variation in $A_{\mu}$, essentially why you believe there should be an extra term.

Comment: @triatticus My thinking process is basically the product rule on the second term or does that not apply?

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$A_\mu \partial^\mu \alpha = g^{\mu\nu}A_\mu \partial_\nu \alpha = A^\nu \partial_\nu \alpha$$

That should resolve your issue and the missing factor of 2.

Comment: Thank you very very much. That makes a lot of sense. I should have seen that but I was quite tired. Happy new year and thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a straight-forwards replacement:
$$
F=\partial_\mu A^\mu+\frac{\lambda}{2}A_\mu A^\mu\\
\delta F = \partial_\mu \delta A^\mu+\frac{\lambda}{2}(\delta A_\mu A^\mu+A_\mu \delta A^\mu)\\
\delta F = \partial_\mu \delta A^\mu+\frac{\lambda}{2}(\delta A^\mu A_\mu+A_\mu \delta A^\mu)\\
\delta F = \partial_\mu \delta A^\mu+\lambda A_\mu\delta A^\mu)\\
\delta F = \partial_\mu \partial^\mu\alpha+\lambda A_\mu\partial^\mu\alpha)\\
\delta F = (\partial_\mu +\lambda A_\mu)\partial^\mu\alpha)\\
$$

Three remarks:

- To take the variation of the product you treat the to A's you have there as two independent terms, to make it more obvious that you simply gain a factor of two.
- Whenever you have and equal index up and down, you can swap their position, as you sum over them anyways (so called dummy indices).
- As you mentioned QED: aboves steps are only true if $[A_\mu,\delta A^\mu]=0$, i.e. they commute. So, as long as A is not a operator you are fine.

Comment: I was not aware that I could do $\delta A_\mu A^\mu = \delta A^\mu A_\mu$, thank youn very much.

Comment: Yes, because $x^\mu y_\mu = g_{\mu\nu}x^\mu y^\nu = x_\mu y^\mu$.